# How to display an Hebrew mapbox?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, hebrew

How to present an Hebrew mapbox? (https://www.mapbox.com/)

I'm using mapbox-gl-js.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/change-language/

Comment: Not relly... 
It doesn't works.
I didn't find the Hebrew solution yet

Comment: Do you have eny Hebrew working example?

Answer (score 2):

Mapbox does not include support for worldwide Hebrew labels, per [this Github issue](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-language/issues/15).

However, if you select "Local" as the language in Mapbox Studio, then it will show the labels in Hebrew in Israel only.

[image: Hebrew map]

Comment: Thank you! its look like good starting.
Now I need to find how to do it by code settings in gl-js.